Do the zeroes of some hypergeometric functions interlace?
Confluent hypergeometric functions differing from $F={}_1F_1(a,b,z)$ by $\pm1$ in either parameter $a$ or $b$ are called contiguous to $F$. For rational $a, b$, assume I know $z_0$ is a zero of $F$. What is known about the relationship between $z_0$ and the zeroes of its contiguous functions?
For Bessel functions we know that in the analogous situation, $z_0$, being a zero of $J_a$ could not be the zero of $J_{a+1}$ because the zeroes of "contiguous" Bessel functions exhibit an interlacing property.
This is cross-posted from mathstackexchange.
I haven't been able to find any information that I can interpret to be useful to me. I've looked at the big references - Slater's book, and Abramowitz and Stegun etc.
I think I want to be able to say something like "since $z_0$ is a zero of $F(a,b,z)$, it is not a zero of at least $F(a+1,b,z)$, or even of $F(a+n,b,z)$ for positive integer $n$ At least for large enough $n$."
I have read that there are a finite number of real zeroes of $F$ for fixed, real $a,b$ but I can't see how to leverage this yet.

This has been studied in: Interlacing of the zeros of contiguous hypergeometric functions (2008):

In terms of the Laguerre function
$L_\nu^\alpha(x)={{\nu+\alpha}\choose\nu}{}_1F_1(-\nu,\alpha+1,x)$ one
has the property that the zeroes of $L_\nu^\alpha(x)$ and
$L_{\nu'}^{\alpha'}(x)$ interlace in $(0,\infty)$ when the differences $\delta \nu=\nu-\nu'\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\delta \alpha=\alpha-\alpha'\in\mathbb{Z}$ (not both zero) satisfy $|\delta\nu|\leq 1$ and $|\delta \nu+\delta \alpha|\leq 1$.

There are additional cases where the zeroes interlace on $(0,\infty)$:

$\delta\nu=0$, $\delta\alpha=2$, $\alpha\geq 0$,
$\delta\nu=-\delta\alpha=2$, $\alpha\leq 0$,
$\delta\alpha=-2\delta\nu=4$, $|\alpha|\leq 1$, $\alpha\neq 0$.


Thank you! Do you know by any chance if anything is known about hg function of the form pFp in general, not just 1F1?

the paper I cite considers $_2F_1$, $_1F_1$, and $_0F_1$, presumably if one studies this carefully a generalisation to $_pF_q$ is possible, but I do not know of a published study of this type.
